# patsubst with multiple wildcards

Tags: makefile

I have a directory structure like

```
packages/
  foo/
    lib/
      a.js
      b.js
  bar/
    lib/
      c.js
      d.js
```

and I'm trying to write a simple `Makefile` to run the source files through a compiler and output the result of compiling `packages/foo/lib/a.js` to `packages/foo/build/a.js`. In the past, I've done something like

```
JS = $(shell find packages/foo/lib -name "*.js")
BUILD = $(patsubst packages/foo/lib/%.js, packages/foo/build/%.js, $(JS))

.PHONY: all
all: $(BUILD)

packages/foo/lib/%.js: packages/foo/build/%.js
  # Compile $^ and output to $@
```

which works great. However, I'm now doing

```
JS = $(shell find packages/*/lib -name "*.js")
BUILD = $(patsubst ...)
```

The problem here is that `patsubst` doesn't seem to like multiple `%` wildcards (ie `packages/%/lib/%.js`). However, if I use `packages/%.js`, then I can't know which directory to use in the substitution. I'm convinced there's a very simple way to do this that I can't find in the make docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define `BUILD`, you could use the stupid but simple solution:

```
BUILD = $(subst /lib/,/build/,$(JS))
```

as long as you aren't worried about additional "lib" and "build" pathname components in your source.

However, this leaves you with the problem of how to define the actual Makefile rules, unless you want to manually specify a rule for each directory `foo`, `bar`, etc.

Instead, maybe try something like this (remember to replace spaces with tabs again where appropriate, if you cut and paste):

```
PACKAGES = $(wildcard packages/*)

ALL :=

define add_package
JS := $$(shell find $(1)/lib -name "*.js")
BUILD := $$(patsubst $(1)/lib/%.js, $(1)/build/%.js, $$(JS))
$(1)/build/%.js:: $(1)/lib/%.js
        echo COMPILE $$^ '->' $$@
        cp $$^ $$@  # super fast compiler!
ALL += $$(BUILD)
endef

$(foreach p, $(PACKAGES), \
  $(eval $(call add_package,$(p))))

all: $(ALL)
```

This evaluates a template for each package directory, so you can put anything in there, as long as you get the fiddly doubling of dollar signs correct.

Comment: Wow nice one! Thanks so much. And my goodness the `cp` compiler seems really fast compared to others I looked into like `babel` and `traceur` ;)